# Should I always implement a move-semantic for functions and methods?

Tags: c++, performance, move-semantics

Does it make sense to overload `set(/*args*/)` with move?:

```
//example:
class Person {
private:

    //properties
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    std::string favmovie;

public:

    //set without operator=
    void set(const std::string& name, const std::string& address, const std::string& favmovie) {
        this->name = name;
        this->address = address;
        this->favmovie = favmovie;

        return;
    }

    //set without operator=
    void set(std::string&& name, std::string&& address, std::string&& favmovie) {
        this->name = std::move(name);
        this->address = std::move(address);
        this->favmovie = std::move(favmovie);

        return;
    }

    Person(const std::string& name, const std::string& address, const std::string& favmovie) 
    : name(name), address(address), favmovie(favmovie) {

    }

    Person(std::string&& name, std::string&& address, std::string&& favmovie) 
    : name(std::move(name)), address(std::move(address)), favmovie(std::move(favmovie)) {

    }

};
```

It feels like copy and paste with a little bit of editing but I'm doing this to every function or method with congruent purposes I have so far to make them high-performing. But is this a good practice?

Comment: const-ref binds to rvalues.

Comment: `cout` isn't going to move the value from `toPrint`, so, no, this isn't affecting performance at all.

Comment: generally speaking, it's better to just use the default-generated `operator=` than provide this set function. avoid code repetition and possibility of errors.

Comment: Check out Herb's excellent lecture about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64&t=53m16s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@M.M's answer has the disadvantage that storage will be reallocated every time `set` is called, while passing the arguments by reference will allow the data to simply be copy-assigned without reallocation whenever their capacity is already sufficient to hold the data passed in via the arguments. See [Herb Sutter's CppCon talk](http://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=1h23m36s) for more details. So I would recommend

```
void set(const std::string &name, const std::string &adress, const std::string &favmovie)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->adress = adress;
    this->favmovie = favmovie;
}
```

The constructors could use the clever pass-by-value trick, but unless it is really low level code that gets beat on a lot the optimization there is likely not worth it, IMO.

Comment: Always - these aren't being modified in the function.

Comment: This avoids that completely - just does copy assignment.

Comment: Well, shouldn't we add the same just with (values...&&) and then move the data?

Comment: It isn't worth it - the problem is there are eight overloads that you'd have to add for completeness (move name, copy address and favmovie, etc.). KISS instead!

Comment: I guess compilers know themselves when they should use it. At least in the Release build which is supported by some compilers

Answer (score 2):

This is where you use pass-by-value:

```
void set(std::string name, std::string adress, std::string favmovie)
{
    this->name = std::move(name);
    this->adress = std::move(adress);
    this->favmovie = std::move(favmovie);
}
```

Then if the argument is an rvalue it will be moved into the parameter than then moved into `this`  - two moves, no copies.  Whereas with the const lvalue reference version, there is always a copy.  For the case of an lvalue argument there is 1 copy in both cases (and 1 extra move in the value version, but moves are cheap and may be elided anyway).

Comment: Has Herb's advice on this changed? In the 2014 CppCon talk (ref's by Snps above) he recommends against this: https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=1h6m48s

Comment: @sfjac I saw that video. I presume you're right. He showed us that construction is way more expensive than assignment. https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=1h23m36s -> can be seen here. I offer you to write this as an detailed answer (I think it's important) else I'd do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the function's purpose itself does not benefit from move semantics, and the function would not benefit from having a reference to a mutable parameter, there is no reason to have an overloaded version that takes an rvalue reference as a parameter.

For the simple function shown here, the answer is obviously no. But it wouldn't be too hard to think of an example where the function would store its parameter someplace. In that case, having an overloaded version that takes advantage of move semantics, instead of having to copy-construct the object for the purpose of storing it, would have obvious benefits.

It all comes down to what the function needs its parameter for.